# Transcendental over a field of transcendental

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

> Say I have a field $F$, and $a,b$ are transcendental over $F$. Can I say that $a$ is algebraic over $F(b)$?

**Edit.** What if $b$ is a monic polynomial in terms of $a$? Would that guarantee that $a$ is algebraic over $F(b)$?

Comment: Why should that be true?

Comment: Suppose $a=b$.  Or $a=b+1$ if you implicitly meant to assume $a\neq b$

Comment: A more general example comes from Luroth theorem. If $F$ is any field and $a$ is transcendental over $F$ and $b\in F(a) \setminus F$ then $b$ is also transcendental over $F$ and $a$ is algebraic over $F(b) $.

Answer (score -1):

Take the field $\Bbb Q$ and as transcendental numbers $\pi$ and $2\pi$ over $\Bbb Q$.
Then $2\pi$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ as you can take the linear polynomial $x - 2\pi\in\Bbb Q(\pi)[x]$ with zero $2\pi$.

Comment: Note $\pi$ and $2\pi$ are not transcendental over $\mathbb{R}$ as they satisfy the polynomial $x-\pi$ and $x-2\pi$.

Comment: Surely this is a typo, and $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb Q$. No need to downvote.